# Constant dbhost already defined in /opt/lampp/htdocs/crud/bd.php on line 6

Tags: php

estoy llamando a un objeto mysqli que conecta la base de datos, el problema es que lo llamo dos veces en el mismo archivo para dos objetos que heredan mysqli y me sale este error:
`Constant dbhost already defined in /opt/lampp/htdocs/crud/bd.php on line 6`
lo mismo con dbnombre,bdusuario y pasword. No se como arreglarlo si alguien pudiera ayudarme gracias.
Para terminar todo el codigo funciona, solo que me lanza ese error al inicio y luego se ejecuta correctamente.
Objeto que conecta

```
<?php
     
  Class Datomysqli{
    protected static $conection;
    public function Datomysqli(){
      define ('dbhost','localhost');
      define ('dbnombre','CRuD'); 
      define ('dbusuario','root');
      define ('dbpasword',''); 
       self:: $conection=new mysqli(dbhost,dbusuario,dbpasword,dbnombre);
       if(self:: $conection->connect_errno){ 
        die ("fallo la conexion a la base de datos");
       }
      return;
    } 
 }
?>
```

Objetos que heredan

```
<?php
    require('bd.php');
   class Imprime extends Datomysqli{
        public function Imprime(){
             parent::__construct();
         }
         public function imprimidor($entrada){
             $pagina=$entrada;  
             $final=2;
             $ini=($pagina-1)*$final;
             $sql='SELECT * FROM tareas LIMIT '.$ini.','.$final.'';//$final es la cantidad de vecez que se va a hacer el select
             $resultado=self::$conection->query($sql);
             if($resultado && $resultado->num_rows>0){
                 $producto=array();
                while($v=$resultado->fetch_All(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    $producto=$v;
                }
                 $resultado=null;
                 self:: $conection=null;
                return $producto;
             }else{
                echo "no se encontro ";exit;
             }
            
         }
    }
 
    Class LIMIT extends Datomysqli{
        public function LIMIT(){
            parent::__construct();
        }
        public function limitador(){
             $sql='SELECT * FROM tareas';
             $resultado=self::$conection->query($sql);
             $nfind=0;
             while($resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
                $nfind++;
             }
             $resultado=null;
             self::$conection=null;
             return $nfind;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: es una paginacion, el primer objeto hace la llamada para imprimir los datos y el segundo objeto hace la paginacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude aislar el problema y creo saber qué es lo que ocurre. El problema pasa porque tienes un método para definir constantes, el cual se está ejecutando varias veces en el mismo script, porque está siendo llamado desde diferentes clases en un mismo archivo. Las constantes solo se pueden definir una vez en un script y por eso da el error.

Vamos a verlo en un ejemplo más simplificado. Una funcion que define 2 constantes y luego esa función es llamada en el constructor de una clase. La clase solo tiene un método adicional que imprime el array de constantes. Simple.

```
<?php
function f0() {
    define('CONS1', 'valor1');
    define('CONS2', 'valor2');
    return array(CONS1, CONS2);
}

class cl1 {
    function __construct() {
        $this->conn = f0();
    }
    
    public function imprimir() {
        print_r($this->conn);
    }
}

// Si se crea un objeto y se imprime, no pasa nada:
$obj1 = new cl1();
$obj1->imprimir(); // array('valor1', 'valor2')

/* Si se instancia otro objeto, entonces este ejecutará otra vez la función f0(), 
la cual intentará crear otra vez las constantes que ya han sido creadas.*/
$obj2 = new cl1();
// PHP Notice: Constant CONS1 already defined
// PHP Notice: Constant CONS2 already defined
```

¿Cómo resolverlo? pues asegurandose de que solo se ejecute el `define()` de una constante solo una vez.
Podrías hacer un archivo que defina las constantes del sitio, como un `config.php` el cual entonces es solicitado en la cabecera del archivo de la clase padre o por otras clases según se requiera.

Pero si quieres resolver de forma rápida el asunto, entonces puedes agregarle una verificación si la constante ya existe antes de tratar de definirla, de cualquiera de las dos formas que muestro.

```
// Cambiar define ('dbhost','localhost'); por
if(!defined('dbhost')) define('dbhost', 'localhost'); // Una forma
// Cambiar define ('dbnombre','CRuD'); por
defined('dbnombre') or define('dbnombre', 'CRuD'); // Otra forma
. // Y asi sucesivamente
.
.
```

Comment: gracias, acabo de agregar el ```config.php``` y funciona perfecto, me salvaste la vida porque llevaba dos dias en eso.